# The principle of converting between APK and AAB files

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to know The principle of converting between APK and AAB files. Can you explain to me more about how to convert between APK and AAB

I have researched but do not understand this well. I hope someone can explain it clearly and understandably to me. Thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/faq

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me the difference in architecture of AAB and APK. is it that there is a META_INF in the APK and AAB does not have a META_INF

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.